# Finding mongoDB documents by a Boolean attribute via mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Why can't I find documents from my MongoDB via mongoose if the attribute is a Boolean?

My Model:

```
var PerformerSchema = new Schema({
    _id: Number,
    firstname: String,
    lastname: String,
    active: Boolean
});
```

My Controller / Search Query:

```
Performer.find({
    'active': true
}, function(err, performers) {
    if (err) {
        return handleError(res, err);
    }
    if (!performers) {
        return res.send(404);
    }
    return res.json(performers);
});
```

This way the returned 'performers' array is empty. But if I change the type of the 'active' attribute in the model from Boolean to String the same Search Query finds the correct documents from my Mongo collection.

Comment: Are you sure your data in db is set with a bool value and not a string ?

Comment: No sorry that's not what I wanted to say. But I use Mongoose too and the boolean values work fine so I wanted to be sure the error is not on storage.

Comment: Don't worry, it was just a joke. But you guessed right and I fixed it. So thank you :)

Comment: Oh sorry I'm not english speaking so I have still problem understanding jokes in english. :)